# Multiple Header in Gridview

Tags: android, list, gridview, scrollview

How can i create multiple header in single grid view like below image. please help me i try scroll view but i failed to create like that.i m try to dynamical image view and text view in scroll view but it can't view like that.i m try to https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/tree/master/Example use but i cant understand that library code

---

[image: here is image i want same like that image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my solution.Its help full for other i can use https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader. and make that type of view.